# Oracle Pipe Line Return ORA-06548: no more rows needed , ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than

Tags: oracle, pipeline

I have written a function that is used to return the BALANCE based on the product type. I am having multiple for each product type and i have used pipe row as follows.

```
create or replace function GETACC_BAL(pi_CUS_MDB_IID  in number,
                                                   pi_EN_TYPE    in varchar2,
                                                   pi_ADC_IID     in number,
                                                   pi_CUS_MDB_IID in number,
                                                   pi_expiryDate     in Date)
return ACC_CUS_BAL_ARR pipelined as


begin
        for i in (select *
                    from CUST_BAL
                   where CUS_MDB_IID = pi_CUS_MDB_IID
                     and EN_TYPE = pi_EN_TYPE
                     and ADC_IID = pi_ADC_IID
                     and BALANCE <> 0) loop

                        pipe row(AC_CUS_BAL(I.EXPDATE,
                                               I.ADC_IID,   
                                               I.EN_TYPE,
                                               I.BALANCE,
                                               'A'
                                               ));
        end loop;

        return;
end GETACC_BAL;
```

/

when i execute the above function where the loop produce one row is working but in case of multiples rows then i ORA-06548;ORA-01427.  I have tried using when_no_data_needed exception , but no luck.

Can someone help on this, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please add procedure `AC_CUS_BAL` also in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception handling for ORA-06548. Although you get an error, it is merely meant as a warning: the pipelined function would produce more rows than you fetch from it, as in

```
select * from my_pipelined_function where rownum = 1;
```

The function is not through, but you stop at the first row in this example and accordingly get the "warning" exception.

Add the following exception catching line to your function to swallow this exception:

```
  ...
  return;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN NULL;
end GETACC_BAL;
```